# Graphing (even with consecutive values)

Tags: c#, graph

I have this code:

```
       var temp = allsuminterestarray.OrderBy(i => int.Parse(i)).GroupBy(i => i);
       int[] forvaluescount = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 
                                    11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 
                                    21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 
                                    31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40,
                                    41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50};



        int j = 0;
        foreach (var val in temp)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(val.Key + " " + val.Count());

            while ((forvaluescount[j] < Convert.ToInt32(val.Key)) && (forvaluescount[j] != Convert.ToInt32(val.Key)))
            {
                probabilities.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(forvaluescount[j], 0/trials);
                j++;
            }

            j++;
            probabilities.Series["Series1"].Points.AddXY(val.Key, val.Count()/trials);


        }
```

NOTE: `temp` has pair values. For example:
(11, 1), 
(14, 1), 
(18, 1), 
(19, 3), 
(20, 1), 
(21, 3), 
(22, 1), 
(24, 3), 
(27, 1), 
(29, 2), 
(30, 1), 
(31, 2) as X and Y values for a chart in C#.

Basically what happens here is that say i have a value of 11 for `val.Key`. The code should work such that it will assign to a CHART values of 1-10 as X and 0 as Y. Then 11 as X with its corresponding Y value.

The loop will continue such that there will be no  missing values in between the values of `temp`.

I believe there's nothing wrong with the code as it output consecutive values.

The problem here is that even if i do the plotting of X and Y in order i get a graph like this:

[image]

I was expecting a similar image to this (this was generated only with the values of `temp`:

[image]

However there should be no missing plots of (X,0).

Please help and thank you!

Comment: Your code looks strange. What is the type of `allsuminterestarray`? The `forvaluescount` array can be constructed easier with `Enumerable.Range`. But it looks like your access `forvaluescount[j]` can be replaced with `j+1`, so I don't see the point?

Comment: @jeppeStigNielsen thank you for your comment. `allsuminterest` is a string array. however your answers as to how the array can be constructed is regardless as to how to solve the problem of charting. Unless i missed our a point you your comment. Thank you! :)

Comment: Also the division `0/trials` seems strange. Did you mean just zero? The zero gives a lot of points on the bottom line of your chart.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen that was an attempt to try and probably correct whatever what was going wrong. Whatever happens the result will still be 0 so thats okay.

Actually that's the point. I need the graph to go down to zero at point where there was no instance of that number (in the X axis). However as i stated above when i put those points, it turns up as an error as in the first image.